# Glossaries: Pagebreak between header and glossary

Tags: page-breaking, glossaries

I'm using the glossaries package to create a list of acronyms. Unfortunately, there occurs a weird page break between the section heading and the actual list:

[image: Image illustrating problem]

## EDIT:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[
acronym,
automake,
style=super]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{alf}{alf}{awesome latex forum}

\begin{document}
    \twocolumn
    \section{Section}

    \lipsum[66]
    \lipsum[66]
    \lipsum[66]
    \lipsum[66]
    \lipsum[66]
    \gls{alf}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE, where you reproduce this behavior in your document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the text before the list of acronyms ends exactly at the end of the column. The solution is to add `\newpage` before `\printglossary`. Quite counterintuitive from my perspective, to add `\newpage` to prevent a page break, but maybe someone with more experience can shed some light on this phenomenon.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[
acronym,
automake,
style=super]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{alf}{alf}{awesome latex forum}

\begin{document}
    \twocolumn
    \section{Section}

    \lipsum[66]
    \lipsum[66]
    \lipsum[66]
    \lipsum[66]
    \lipsum[66]
    \gls{alf}
    \newpage
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```